# Namespace not attaching to bool in WCF unless different from class's Namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

I have a datatype I'm using in WCF for sending a SOAP response. It looks like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <start-call-recording-response xmlns="http://foobar">
         <response>true</response>
      </start-call-recording-response>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The issue is that the namespace (`http://foobar`) is not appearing in the  element. That is, UNLESS I change the XmlElementAttibute's Namespace to something different from the parent class's XmlRootAttribute's Namespace. Here is the class for start-call-recording-response:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18033")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName = "StartcallrecordingresponseType")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar", ElementName = "start-call-recording-responseType")]
public partial class StartcallrecordingresponseType
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar")]
    private bool responseField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://foobar", ElementName = "response", IsNullable = false)]
    public bool Response
    {
        get
        {
            return this.responseField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.responseField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the XmlElementAttribute's Namespace above Response to something other than the namespace of the containing class, it will appear in the SOAP envelope's . If they're the same, it doesn't appear. Tried many variations of XmlTypeAttributes, XmlRootAttributes, and XmlElementAttributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. See the [namespace spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#defaulting)

> The scope of a default namespace declaration extends from the beginning of the start-tag in which it appears to the end of the corresponding end-tag, excluding the scope of any inner default namespace declarations. In the case of an empty tag, the scope is the tag itself.

So the response element inherits the foobar namespace from its start-call-recording-response parent.